The Scapegoat and the Scarlet Wool - Epistle of Barnabas
The Epistle of Barnabas is a second century text classified as one of the Apostolic Fathers, Greek texts which immediately follow the New Testament, which is studied by New Testament specialists.
In chapter 7, the author appears to quote a known Jewish tradition regarding the Torah's Scapegoat practice:

"Spit on it, all of you; thrust your goads into it, wreathe its head with scarlet wool, and so let it be driven out into the desert." (Maxwell Staniforth's translation from Early Christian Writings: the Apostolic Fathers)

This practice of scarlet wool does not appear in the Tanakh (OT) as far as I can discern - do we have any idea when this tradition appeared or was first evidenced, and particularly whether it would be well known by the time of Jesus?

Zerah's scarlet ribbon is also τὸ κόκκινον = שָׁנִי - so there might be a prior question whether the symbol is symbolizing the ritual or additional to it. One imagines the Genesis usage would be foundational to the others but Zerah isn't a scapegoat and it's not obvious why it's mentioned there. Which might mean the symbol's meaning derives from other stories. But I begin to think aloud

The biblical origin of the tradition of the scarlet wool is obscure. However, it seems to have been practiced from antiquity. A miracle is recorded regarding this wool turning white during the time of the high priest Shimon Ha-Tzaddik c. 313 bce. According to the Talmud Yoma 39a

During his tenure as High Priest, the strip of crimson wool that was
tied to the head of the goat that was sent to Azazel turned white,
indicating that the sins of the people had been forgiven, as it is
written: “Though your sins be as crimson, they shall be white as snow”
(Isaiah 1:18). From then onward, it sometimes turned white and
sometimes it did not turn white.

The Epistle of Barnabas was written c. 100 ce, so it is likely that the author was aware of the scarlet wool tradition that was later recorded in the Talmud.

This will not answer the question but simply supply what is known (or unknown) in the Biblical text.
First, "scarlet wool" occurs in the Epistle of Barnabas 7:8 concerning the scapegoat ceremony on the day of atonement in Lev 16.  As best I can determine, the only place this occurs in the NT is in Heb 9:19 where we read:

For when Moses had proclaimed every commandment of the law to all the
people, he took the blood of calves and goats, along with water,
scarlet wool, and hyssop, and sprinkled the scroll and all the people

However, this is describing events in Ex 24 at the confirmation of the Covenant.
However, in the OT, "scarlet" is a consistent symbol of the sin as per Isa 1:18 -

“Come now, let us reason together,” says the LORD. “Though your sins
are like scarlet, they will be as white as snow; though they are
as red as crimson, they will become like wool.

In almost all other places, the noun "scarlet" occurs alone.  It is usually the translators that add "wool", "cloth", or "yarn" after it as an interpretive translation.  The exception is Num 4:8 discussing the tabernacle construction.
